# jQuery ScrollTop acceleration

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I have a jquery script for scrollTop and trying to work out why it accelerates after it starts.  It starts of slow and then gets faster.

Is there a way to stop the lag at the beginning and make it the same speed throughout the whole scroll?

```
// When DOM is fully loaded
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    function scroll(speed) {
        $('.shooter-scroller').animate({ scrollTop: $('.shooter-scroller').prop('scrollHeight') }, speed, function() {
            $(this).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, speed);
        });
    }
    speed = 80000;

    scroll(speed)
    setInterval(function(){scroll(speed)}, speed * 2);      
});
```

Fiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/andysimps1985/gn1a2kn7/10/

Comment: Try this: `$(this).animate({ scrollTop: 0, easing: "linear"}, speed);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) has an easing property which by default is set to `swing`. Changing the easing property to `linear` will give you the constant speed you're looking for.

Here is an example of your code with the easing property.

```
// When DOM is fully loaded
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    function scroll(speed) {
        $('.shooter-scroller').animate({
            scrollTop: $('.shooter-scroller').prop('scrollHeight'),
            easing: 'linear'
        }, {
            duration: speed,
            easing: 'linear', // <--- here
            complete: function () {
                $(this).animate({
                    scrollTop: 0
                }, {
                    duration: speed,
                    easing: 'linear', // <--- here
                    complete: speed
                });
            }
        });
    }

    speed = 8000;

    scroll(speed)
    setInterval(function () {
        scroll(speed)
    }, speed * 2);

});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gn1a2kn7/11/)

Comment: Beat me by 30 seconds... I approve this message!

Answer (score 1):

JQuery is designed to have a scroll in that form.
You could try out : https://github.com/ArthurClemens/jquery-page-scroll-plugin which supports constant speed scroll too.